# NX EACCES: permission denied

Tags: reactjs, frontend, micro-frontend, nomachine-nx

I am trying to start my nx framework application but i couldn;t getting an error

> NX   EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/hariharan.ravichandran/.config/fork-ts-checkerrc'

Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

> NX   Running target serve for project host-shell failed

Failed tasks:

- host-shell:serve:development

Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.

every time when i start i get this error looks like a permission error

Comment: did you try to follow the instructions and run it with the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: its just showing the same error with more of an informationnpm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 51ms
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠴ : timing npm:load Completed in 94ms
> nx run administrative-profile:build:development

 >  NX   EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/hariharan.ravichandran/.config/fork-ts-checkerrc'
   Pass --verbose to see the stacktrace.
(⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠴ : timing npm:load Completed in 94ms
 ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

Comment: please put the full error message as text in your question. Also, the error is about permissions, did you make sure the user running the script has read/write access to that file mentioned there?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows. You should try restarting Windows NAT Driver service.

Open Command Prompt as Administrator and run

`net stop winnat`

then

`net start winnat`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's an ownership issue with the files in your project `node_modules`.

Try these steps in console:

1. check who is your current user (say the result reads `hariharan`):

```
whoami
```

2. go to the root folder of your project (usually, the one containing `node_modules`) and run this command to see who is the owner of `node_modules` contents:

```
ls -al ./node_modules
```

I expect the result will go sth along the line of (the `root` suggests the owner is `root` and you need to change it to your user from step-1:

```
drwxr-xr-x     3 root  staff       96 Oct 12  2022 some-file-or-folder-name
```

3. Change ownership from `root` --> `hariharan` for all files and folders recursively (`-R`) with this command:

```
sudo chown -R hariharan: ./
```

4. Try re-run your `nx` command